# Sweet Alert 2 - why can't I target by class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, dom

I'm using Sweet Alert 2 and can't seem to target by class when there is more than 1 element of the same class.

For example, I have a table which outputs a list of records and a 'delete' button next to each one, e.g.

```
 <a class="delete-course" href="#">Delete Course</a>
```

The js I have targets by `.delete-course` :

```
document.querySelector('.delete-course').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('delete course pressed');

    // ...
});
```

All of the code works fine, if there's only 1 'delete course' button. But if I have multiple buttons, it will only fire when clicking the first one. For example:

```
<!-- 1 --> <a class="delete-course" href="#">Delete Course</a>
<!-- 2 --> <a class="delete-course" href="#">Delete Course</a>
<!-- 3 --> <a class="delete-course" href="#">Delete Course</a>
```

It will work for `<!-- 1 -->` but not `<!-- 2 -->` or `<!-- 3 -->`

Why is this? I assumed that because I was targeting by class, it will fire when *any* element of that class is clicked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`querySelector` returns the first element that matches the criteria:

> Returns the first Element within the document (...) that matches the specified group of selectors.
>
> Source:
>   [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Instead use `querySelectorAll` combined with a `forEach`- see demo below:

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.delete-course'), function(e) {
  e.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('delete course pressed');
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- 1 --><a class="delete-course" href="#">Delete Course</a>
<!-- 2 --><a class="delete-course" href="#">Delete Course</a>
<!-- 3 --><a class="delete-course" href="#">Delete Course</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

`querySelectorAll` with a `for loop` is expensive as it creates a new event handler for each element in the array.

> Instead, create one event handler which is attached to the body
>   element with the defined class.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains("delete-course")) {
    var title = event.target.innerHTML;

    //if (!confirm("Sure to " + title)) {
      //event.preventDefault();
    //}
swal(
  'All right',
  'Deleted! '+title,
  'success'
)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://tristanedwards.me/u/SweetAlert/lib/sweet-alert.css"/>
<script src="http://tristanedwards.me/u/SweetAlert/lib/sweet-alert.js"></script>
<a class="delete-course" href="#">Delete Course1</a>

<a class="delete-course" href="#">Delete Course2</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this snippet all a tag are calling sweet alert

```js
$(".delete-course").click(function() {
    sweetAlert(
        "Deleted...", "Successfully!", "success"
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://tristanedwards.me/u/SweetAlert/lib/sweet-alert.css"/>
<script src="http://tristanedwards.me/u/SweetAlert/lib/sweet-alert.js"></script>
<!-- 1 --><a class="delete-course" href="#">Delete Course</a>
<!-- 2 --><a class="delete-course" href="#">Delete Course</a>
<!-- 3 --><a class="delete-course" href="#">Delete Course</a>
```